# Show that a rational number $m\in [a,b]$ is obtainable iff $m= \frac{x}{2^n}a + \frac{2^n-x}{2^n} b$ where $0\leq x\leq 2^n$ is an integer.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

(This question was edited from the original). For an interval $[a,b]$ with a and b rational, let S be defined as follows: $a,b$ are in S. For any $x,y$ in S, $(x+y)/2$ is in S. S is the set of obtainable numbers. Show that a rational number $m\in [a,b]$ is obtainable iff $m= \frac{x}{2^n}a + \frac{2^n-x}{2^n} b$ where $0\leq x\leq 2^n$ is an integer.

(If part). Observe that $ m = \frac{x}{2^n} a+\frac{2^n-x}{2^n}b$ is clearly obtainable for $n=0$ and $x=0,1$. Now assume inductively that for all $0\leq x\leq 2^n, m=\frac{x}{2^n} a + \frac{2^n-x}{2^n} b$ is obtainable for all $n < k,k \ge 1$. We want to show that $m = \frac{x}{2^k} a + \frac{2^k-x}{2^k} b$ is obtainable for all $0\leq x\leq 2^k$. If $x$ is even, the result holds by the inductive hypothesis so suppose $x$ is odd. Write $x = 2q + 1$ for some $q$. Then $2^k - x = 2(2^{k-1} - q) - 1$. Then $x$ is clearly the average of $\frac{q}{2^{k-1}}a + \frac{2^{k-1}-q}{2^{k-1}}b$ and $\frac{q+1}{2^{k-1}}a + \frac{2^{k-1} - (q+1)}{2^{k-1}}b$, both of which are obtainable numbers by the inductive hypothesis (indeed $x=2q + 1\leq 2^k - 1$, so $0\leq q < q + 1 \leq 2^{k-1}$).

(Only if part). We show that if $m\in [a,b]$ is obtainable, then $m=\frac{x}{2^n} a + \frac{2^n - x}{2^n}b$ where $0\leq x\leq 2^n$ is an integer. Observe that obtainable numbers are closed under taking the arithmetic mean. We use induction on the number of steps/applications to obtain a number. For $n=0,1$ steps the possibilities are $a,b,\frac{a+b}2$, all of which have the required form. Now suppose inductively that all obtainable numbers are of the described form after $n$ steps for all $n < k,$ some $k\ge 2$. The step before the $k$th step, we took the arithmetic mean of two obtainable numbers of the described form. But observe that $\frac{1}2 (\frac{x}{2^n} a + \frac{2^n - x}{2^n}b + \frac{y}{2^m} a + \frac{2^m - y}{2^m}b) = \frac{x 2^{m-1} + y 2^{n-1}}{2^{n+m}} a + \frac{2^{n+m} - (x2^{m-1} + y2^{n-1})}{2^{n+m}}b,$ which is of the required form because $0\leq x\leq 2^n, 0\leq y \leq 2^m\Rightarrow 0\leq x2^{m-1} + y2^{n-1}\leq 2^{n+m}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that a rational number $m\in[a, b]$ is obtainable iff $m = \frac{x}{2^n} a + \frac{2^n-x}{2^n} b$ where $0\le x \le 2^n$ is an integer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you justify your answer?

Comment: The slightly easier "only" part can be done by showing those numbers are closed under taking arithmetic mean. To show the "if" part, you just need to do induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to get $\frac{1}{3}$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question but it's still incomplete. Could you add some more details? Also could you verify whether the inductive proof is correct (I just want to make sure)?

Comment: You misunderstood my hint: It's **not** possible to get to $\frac{1}{3}$. It's **not** obtainable.

Comment: How would you obtain $2 \in [1,4]$?

Answer (score 0):

Lets pick $[0,1]$ as the interval. Every attainable number is of the form $\frac{k}{2^q}$ for some nonnegative integer $q$ and some $k \le 2^q$.

Then if $\frac{1}{3}$ is attainable, then the equation $\frac{1}{3}=\frac{k}{2^q}$ yields a solution for some such integers $k$ and $q$. Equivalently, the equation $\frac{2^q}{3}=k$ yields a solution, for some such integers $k$ and $q$.

What if you were to replace $\frac{1}{3}$ with $\frac{1}{c}$ for any odd integer $c \ge 3$.

Now suppose instead of $[0,1]$ your interval is $[0,N]$. Then the numbers attainable are precisely those of the form $\frac{kN}{2^q}$. Does this cover all the integers? What if $N$ has any odd multiples at least $3$. For example, suppose $N$ is a multiple of $3$. Then $\frac{N}{3}$ is integral. Is $\frac{N}{3}$ attainable though? If $\frac{N}{3}$ were attainable, then there exist integers $q$ and $k$ such that $\frac{N}{3}=\frac{kN}{2^q}$, or equivantly $\frac{2^q}{3}=k$.

What if, conversely, $N$ does not have any odd multiples greater than $1$ and is thus a power of $2$ however.

Comment: Actually @user3472, that's not true. Please read my editted answer.